# Count number of null column in sql query result

Tags: sql, count, pivot

I have a table which is queried using pivot and the select statement returns values for Jan,Feb,Mar,....,Dec. Along with this result, i need one more column that displays the count of number of Columns(from Jan to Dec) whose value is null.

This can be done using **case when** and adding 1 for each month when its null....Is there is more efficient way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: It's quite hard to provide an improvement for abstract query in unknown DBMS and with abstract data.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms